# The “Congratulations!” notice on the user profile page is not shown correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, notifications

The “Congratulations!” notice on the user profile page is not shown correctly. 
In this case, the notice is about a new tag badge. A small part of it can be seen below the dark bar.

[image]

I would have expected something like this:

[image]

Comment: *Congratulations! We won't tell you what just happened.*

Answer (score 4):

*Congratulations* for finding the bug... :) This should be fixed now, it'll be live after our next production build.